# Content overflow on mobile and old browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a fixed height and content within this container. I've been using "em" for the font sizing, and its been working for modern version of FireFox and IE. However i went and checked it on my mobile and an old version of IE(6) and the content overflows past the bottom of the container into the footer. So far i've tried changing the height of this container to auto !important and setting the fixed height as a min-height, this did not work. Also i changed the em to corresponding px sizes but this did not work either. The HTML and CSS look something like this.

```css
#container {
    width:570px;
    height:570px;
    font-size:1.2em;
    text-align:left;
   }

#container p {
    margin-left:35px;
    margin-right:35px;
 }

#foot {
    width:570px;
    height:60px;
    clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p>Content1</p> 
    <p>Content2</p>
    <p>Content3</p>
</div>    

<div id="foot">
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Does this container have to be a fixed height?

Comment: It needs to be a fixed height for the sole reason that this container has a container to the left of it and another one to the right of it. I need these containers to all be the same height. This middle container is the only one with content however. If i do 'height:auto !important' they will have different heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden;` to `#container`'s css and a `display: block;` also `height:auto !important;`

```css
#container {
    width:570px;
    height:auto !important;
    display: block;
    font-size:1.2em;
    text-align:left;
   }
```

Comment: Very good fixed the problem i described perfectly! What i left out however is that this container is only my main(middle container) and i have a container to the left of it and another one to the right of it. So in using height:auto these three containers have differing heights. Looked into this aswell and i guess CSS doesnt offer any solutions that i have found so far and i might have to redo using Tables. Cheers though!

Comment: Please my friend, try not to sucumb to tables if you can use any other idea. I sugest using jquery to check heights

Comment: ok so you could do this: 1)add min-height: 570px; to those rules and see if it works fine :)